# Serialization vs Embedded Database for simple standalone application

Tags: java, database, serialization, persistence

Say, I have a pretty simple Java application that needs the way to store some user settings. XML is not a really good solution, since I want to store them in binary form. So, what would be the best solution in this case, embedded database (such as Apache Derby) or just plain old serialization?
I know that these are two completely different things, but both allow to persist some application state. So what would you chose, and why?

**Edit**
As far as storing simple user preferences go, .properties or xml files are fine, I agree with you. But what if I want to store passwords, or some application-specific data?

Comment: "since I want to store them in binary form"?  Why?  Why make it complex?

Comment: well, that's not the general case, but perhaps I would want to prevent a user from editing these settings

Comment: "prevent a user from editing these settings".  That's funny.  What's the real reason?  Seriously, anyone can tweak a binary file with a byte-level editor or a little Python script.

Comment: @S.Lott by anyone, you mean some regular Windows user, who knows only how to use MS Office and IE?

Comment: Yes.  Anyone can tinker with any file using any random tool they downloaded from the internet.  And they often do.  Then they call for support because they broke the application.

Comment: "if I want to store passwords".  May requires encryption; binary is useless for "protecting" this data. "or some application-specific data"?  Again.  Why make this more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: Encryption is a totally different aspect. Of course the question should have been "if I want to store **encrypted** passwords".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apache Derby is an embeddable relational database, it makes sense to use it for storing and manipulating relational data. Using an embedded db for persisting a few user settings only is a bit overkill.

If it were me, I would use a simple key/value pair serialization for persisting user settings.

Comment: You outlined some very important aspects. Such as "use database for relational data" and "don't use a database for storing just a few settings". I totally agree with you. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

User settings are typically stored as

- properties, using the properties file format
- properties using the XML format
- preferences, using the Preferences API. This has the advantage of storing and reading user and system preferences for you, without having to think about where to store them, etc. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Preferences API. I have to read about it. Is this really common? I've never come across this before. Although I must admit, that I've been developing mostly distributed applications, and I often made use of RDBMS, properties and xml files for storing data/configuration settings. But what if I want to store application state, not just some user settings (let's say some internal counter)? And also what about password? I guess it's not really a good idea to keep such data in xml.

Comment: If application state is only some internal counter, I don't see why the preferences API shouldn't be used. If it consists in a huge object graph, then it's another matter. A password, whether stored in a XML file, text file, binary file, database, is always a sensitive piece of information. It should just not be stored without the user accepting it and understanding the risk. But the format doesn't matter.